# what's wrong with the code which is to merge two singly linked list into another list?

Tags: c

I wanna merge two singly linked list like La and Lb into new list like Lc, and lc's head node point to La. There is the code:

```
//something unnecessary code has been cut

typedef struct LNode
{
    ElemType data;
    struct LNode *next;
}LNode, *LinkList;


//merge La and Lb into Lc
Status Algo(LinkList La, LinkList *Lb, LinkList *Lc);

int main()
{
    LinkList La,Lb,Lc;

    CreateListHead_L(&La, 5);  //Crate a list with 5 nodes
    CreateListHead_L(&Lb, 5);
    printf("La:"); ListTraverse_L(La);  
    printf("Lb:"); ListTraverse_L(Lb);

    Algo(La, &Lb, &Lc);

    printf("Lc:");
    ListTraverse_L(Lc);

    return 0;
}

Status Algo(LinkList La, LinkList *Lb, LinkList *Lc)
{
    LinkList p;

    *Lc = La;
    p = La->next;
    if(!p) return ERROR;
    while(p)
        p = p->next;

    p->next = (*Lb)->next;
    free(*Lb);

    return OK;
}
```

I just wanna know what wrong with the function `Algo` which I think that is right. Why the program would crashed when it process the function?

Comment: Using a typedef for a pointer confuses things here a bit. It’s usually best not to do that. This is a great time to learn how to use a debugger. Run the code line by line, see where it crashes and eat the variables are. You haven’t shown a [mcve] so we don’t know what the creation and traversing look like or if the link is terminated correctly. The algo itself should always just return ERROR due to a bug, but not crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely this will run off the end of La and you'll end up holding nothing when what you actually want to be holding is the last node in La, so you can set its next to be the head of Lb (your while loop is trying to find the last node in La but it goes too far and only stops looping after it runs off the end of the list)

I don't do c, but I understand the logic.. really you want to be doing something like

```
while(p->next) //while there is still a next item
```

So that when you get to the last item in La, the loop stops and your p is still the last item, not null